# Starting uipath process from my front end website

Tags: node.js, flask, automation, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I have a UIpath robot that extracts text from a pdf, now I want to attach this robot to my front-end website such that a user uploads a pdf from the front end and in the backend, the UIpath robot extracts text and returns back to the front end.
But I don't know how should I link my website with UIPath, can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options depending on your use case:

1. In case you only run it on you local PC you should use [**Robot.js**](https://docs.uipath.com/robot/docs/about-the-robot-javascript-sdk). This will work properly as it just accesses your local UiPath Assistant. But the downside is that noone else will be able to use it. It's only locally.
2. If you need others or even create a server for you robot, then you will need a package like [**Node.js package**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uipath-orchestrator). I also created a server for our company processes and the business users of the company are now able to control our processes from everywhere. It's pretty simple and safe. The credentials are hidden on the server runtime environment. And the good thing is, the Node.js server does not have to be the server with the robot. You are completely free here.